# Should I use the targetType parameter of the IValueConverter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, ivalueconverter

Every time I am writing a value converter I'm wondering how to handle the `targetType` parameter specified at the `Convert` and `ConvertBack` method of the [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
```

I noticed that many implementations are using the `targetType` simply by checking it (`if (targetType == typeof(RequiredType))`) and throwing some exceptions or returning a null value if the type is not like expected:

- [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Main/Source/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock/Converters/InverseBoolToVisibilityConverter.cs)
- [Silverlight 2 Recipes](https://books.google.de/books?id=jRltgNSP-6wC&lpg=PA283&ots=ECejCac6ZS&dq=if%20(targetType&hl=de&pg=PA283#v=onepage&q=283&f=false)
- [Infragistics](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2011.2/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v11.2~Infragistics.Windows.DataPresenter.Field~Converter.html)

But also many of them (I think it's the majority) are totally ignoring the parameter:

- [WPF tutorial](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/value-conversion-with-ivalueconverter/)
- [Dot net tricks](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2010/03/how-to-use-ivalueconverter-in-binding.html)
- [Code project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/868163/IValueConverter-Example-and-Usage-in-WPF)

I tried to find some guidlines or tips using the parameter but unfortunately I found absolutely nothing.
Both approaches are doing their jobs, but is one of the approaches more correct? What are the pros and cons of the approaches? Should I ignore or use the parameter?

My personal view is not to check the parameter to allow the usage of the converter more flexible but I'm excited to get your opinions.

Comment: the point of that parameter is that the caller will be telling you what to convert it to; if you always ignore them and return the same thing, it isn't any more "flexible" than if you check and throw an exception. Equally, if they only ever ask for the thing you're going to return, then again: it isn't actually any more flexible. In most cases, you'll only be converting to one thing, so it is rarely a genuine issue, hence why a lot of code ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

The caller will be telling you what is the desired type to convert the value:

1. If you know you always will convert to one type, e.g. `true/false` to `Visibility`, then you can just ignore the `targetType`. It's obvious how to use the converter, there is no need for trowing exceptions.
2. Converting the value based on the `targetType`, e.g. using the converter to convert to `ImageSource` or `Brush`. In the first case you want to generate an image (e.g. error image), in the other you want a simple color (e.g. red).
3. If you know that someone might use your converter with a `targetType` you don't want to and it's not obvious if it's supported or not, then you can warn the developer by throwing an exception.

I think most common scenario is the 1).